# Haskell web frameworks survey

Tags: web-development, experience, comparison, web-framework, haskell

There are several web frameworks for Haskell like [Happstack](http://happstack.com/index.html), [Snap](http://snapframework.com/), and [Yesod](http://docs.yesodweb.com/), and probably a few more.

In what aspects do they differ from each other? For example:

- features (e.g. server only, or also client
  scripting, easy support for different kinds of database)
- maturity (e.g. stability, documentation quality)
- scalability (e.g. performance, handy abstraction)
- main targets

Also, what are examples of real-world sites / web apps using these frameworks?

Many thanks.

Comment: +1 Although I don't know Haskell, this could be interesting.

Comment: Are there free hosts available for Haskell websites?  What would the requirements be for a server?

Comment: @Alison - I would assume not since you would most likely need a VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: you could use the free tier at Amazon EC2 I guess for hosting

Comment: I was really hoping to get some people talking about other frameworks (so we could compare)

Answer (score 10):

I can only speak on the behalf of Yesod, since I have only tried Snap and Yesod so far but quickly stuck with Yesod.

The main reason for Yesod is probably that it delivers a complete framework with a growing numbers of features, like

- Typesafe Template Languages for HTML, CSS and JavaScript
- Typesafe Routing
- Splitting into Subsites
- Database integration with Persistent
- Pre-made subsites for re-occuring problems: Authorisation, Static, CRUD...

In my eyes, the big strength of Yesod is the compilation of its dynamic contents, e.g. HTML sites. The template site is parsed via Template Haskell and converted into a Haskell data structure. So the template is not parsed every time the user calls it. In my opinion, this is a major speed advantage, compared to PHP, and also to Snap which uses non-compiled templates, and it also helps a great deal for the scalability.

Yesod is approaching version 1.0 soon, according to its creator, and there are some Websites already running on it. I think the main target of Yesod is to deliver a type-safe, complete web application framework that delivers all your needs, and then some.

Also, Yesod integrates with the WAI-interface and works perfectly with the pure Haskell-server Warp.